# Python function doesn't seem to terminate after return

Tags: python, loops, debugging, iterator

At least that's the most that I can make sense of it, and I've been tracing over the flow of execution for hours. Here's the relevant snippet of the code:

```
def check_list(inputList):
    '''checks if list is composed of numbers, and, if so, returns a new list of purely integers'''
    VerifiedDataSet = []
    for i in inputList:
        try:
            VerifiedDataSet.append(int(i))
        except:
            print("Value in", inputList.index(i) + 1, "position isn't a number!")
            return "not approved"
    return ("approved", VerifiedDataSet)

print("This program will make your data set into a color coded bar graph (eventually)!")

listStatus = "not approved"

while listStatus == "not approved":
    dataSet = ["1", "2", "foo"] #for illustration of behavior
    result = check_list(dataSet)
    listStatus = result[0]
    if listStatus == 'approved':
        dataSet = result[1]
    else:
        pass

print("You should not see this.")
```

The idea was to have the function `check_list` iterate through an inputted list and try converting each element into an integer. If there was an exception, it would print the position of the value that couldn't be converted into an integer and return that the list was not approved, which should 1) terminate the function, and 2) cause the `while` loop below to continue.

Only if there were no exceptions should the iterator complete and the function return both the string "approved" (to terminate the `while` loop) and the new list of integers. However, from what I can gather, `listStatus` is set to "approved" somehow anyway, as the last `print` is executed when it never should be.

Any ideas what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: Might I enquire why you go to such lengths to avoid the `ValueError` from the failed conversion to simply trickle down from `check_list()`?

Comment: @dhke I'm assuming you're hinting that there's a far more efficient way to do what I'm trying to do (and I wouldn't doubt it). The reason for that is that I'm still very new to Python, and programming in general. I've played with exceptions a little bit, but I don't think I would know yet what to do with them, or how to use them to my advantage. Soon maybe! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value being returned from the function is a string. Hence result will have the value "not approved".

`listStatus = result[0]`

This will make `listStatus` = 'n' and not "not approved".

Answer (score 2):

If an exception is raised you are returning `'not approved'` from the function,

which makes `listStatus == 'n'`, therefore the `while` loop breaks.